# Declaring and working with Kinds in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, data-kinds, type-kinds

I've been playing with Haskell's `-XDataKinds` feature quite a lot recently, and have found myself wanting to *create* a kind.

I'm not sure if my wishes can come true, but from Edward Kmett's [constraints package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4.1.3/docs/Data-Constraint.html), there seems to be a declared kind `Constraint` (with sort `BOX`), which says to be defined in `GHC.Prim`, but I couldn't find it.

Is there any way to declare a kind in Haskell or GHC, manually? This would probably need manual assertion that data types declared with `data` would be of the proper kind. My idea is something like the following:

```
data Foo :: BOX

data Bar a :: Foo where
  Bar :: a -> Bar a
```

Comment: The use of `DataKinds` means every data declaration creates a fresh kind, doesn't it? e.g. `data Nat = Z | S Nat` creates a new kind `Nat` inhabited by types `Z :: Nat` and `S :: Nat -> Nat`.

Comment: That's correct, but only if the promoted type is a proper Haskell98 data type. In my case, I'm finding myself needing to promote something that looks like `data Foo (x :: Bar) (y :: Bar) = Foo | ...`, where `Bar` is a kind. This won't promote with `-XDataKinds` - I will need to _manually_ promote it, with the same names. This would also be really useful for wanting to promote GADTs, too.

Comment: I've read your question several times now, and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out just what it is you need/are proposing. It *seems* like you are asking to declare a new kind inhabited by some new types that are themselves inhabited at the term level -- which at the moment is impossible. Is that what you are asking for, or something else? If it's something else, a smallish use case would be quite illuminating. As for promoting GADTs, I believe that is still an open research question.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're very close. I'm not sure if I need the types inhabited at the term level (like singletons), but I very much would like to declare a kind independent of it's types, then ad-hoc declare types to be inhabitants of the previously defined kind.

It's not clear, I know, but if I could simply declare a Kind, then create inhabitant types of that kind in a different expression, that would be ideal. I'm not sure if I _need_ terms for these types, but they wouldn't hurt either.

Ideally, I would like to do `data FooKind :: BOX where`, then `data Bar a :: FooKind where ...`.

Comment: @AthanClark I think you're asking if there's a way to declare new open world kinds in GHC in addition to `k1 -> ... kN -> *` and `k1 -> ... -> kM -> Constraint`.  As far as I know, the answer is "no".  All the other kinds in GHC arise as promotions of (closed) datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current GHC (7.8 at time of writing), one cannot separate the declaration of a fresh kind from the declaration of its type-level inhabitants.

Comment: Systems like Agda help alleviate this need, correct?

Comment: @AthanClark I'm not an Agda expert, and I don't know whether it supports declaring open types (at higher strata) or not. I would be kind of surprised if it did.